# An idiom describing a young adult moving out of parents' house

Tags: idiom-request

Is there any idiom in English likening a person reaching adulthood and moving out of his/her parents' house to a bird leaving the nest made by its parent birds? If not, what idiom in English would commonly describe a young adult moving out of his/her childhood house (the house where he/she was born and grew up)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A grown-up child leaving the parental home is sometimes said to 'fly the nest'. The initial loneliness sometimes felt by parents after their children have left can be called 'empty nest syndrome'.

> fly the nest
>
> phrase
>
> When children fly the nest, they leave their parents' home to live on
>   their own.
>
> *When their children had flown the nest, they moved to a
>   cottage in Dorset.*

[Fly the nest](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fly-the-nest)

Comment: or 'left the nest'

Comment: @JohnFeltz - Or 'kicked out of the nest,' if it's done with some coercion.